# Values on top of Bar Charts on AndroidPlot

Tags: android, charts, androidplot

I'm trying to write one example of Android application using the AndroidPlot library.
That library is excellent, but I couldn't found anything about how to display the value data on the top of each bar in the Bar Chart.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are asking, but from my understanding the bar plot's do not have values on top of each bar. See the sample image (http://androidplot.com/wp-content/gallery/plot-examples/device-2013-06-30-204308.png)

Comment: AChartEngine has this feature...

Comment: I believe androidplot does not, maybe achartengine will be a better tool for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Totally doable.  I actually just answered the question here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/androidplot/TimE-j9VnaY

But for convenience here's a quick snippet that works in Androidplot 0.6.0 and later.  There's also an easy way to do this in previous versions of Androidplot but you'll need to get those details from the thread above.

```
 BarFormatter bf1 = new BarFormatter(Color.RED, Color.BLACK);
 bf1.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter(Color.WHITE));
 plot.addSeries(series1, bf1);
```